Can I make a tkinter.listbox item exclusive from the rest?
So I have a listbox where the user can select multiple items, based on an array made from files in a folder.
Now I need to make an "All"-Item, which should remove the selection from all other items in the list. So basically a selectmode=multiple, with the ability to make that one item exclusive (like shown in the picture below).
Is that possible at all?


That is possible using <<ListboxSelect>> event handler, select_clear function and a custom flag variable.
If a user changes selection and All was previously selected then All should be unselected and the all_selected flag should become False.
When All is selected and the flag is False then the rest of the items should be unselected and the all_selected flag should become True.
from tkinter import *
 
top = Tk()
 
listbox = Listbox(top, selectmode = 'multiple')
listbox.pack_configure(padx = 30, pady = 10)

items = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']

listbox.insert(0, *items)
listbox.insert(listbox.size(), 'All')
listbox.all_selected = False

def on_listbox_select(event):
    lbox = event.widget
    last = lbox.size() - 1

    if lbox.all_selected:
        lbox.select_clear(last)
        lbox.all_selected = False
        return
    
    if last in lbox.curselection():
        lbox.select_clear(0, last - 1)
        lbox.all_selected = True
    
listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_listbox_select)

button = Button(top, text = 'Do some stuff') 
button.pack_configure(pady = 10)

listbox.pack() 
button.pack()
 
top.mainloop()

